# How to close the vs-popup on clicking cancel button in the context of VueJS

Tags: vue.js, popup

I am using the Vuesax vs-popup in order to display my contents on button click, i want to close the vs-popup on clicking cancel button which is inside the vs-popup.

Here is the code:

```
   <vs-button  class="btn"  @click="touchOpen= true">Explore</vs-button>
 <vs-popup title="Welcome to my world" :active.sync="touchOpen">
      <vs-button  class="close"  @click="touchOpen = false" >Cancel</vs-button>
  </vs-popup>
  ....
  data () {
      return {
          touchOpen: false
      }
  }
```

Here I am unable to to close the vs-popup on button click.

And also i want to know how it can be closed automatically when submitting form successfully. Please do help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, just implementing small method can do the job!

**Here is the working code:**

```
 <vs-button  class="btn"  @click="touchOpen= true">Explore</vs-button>
 <vs-popup title="Welcome to my world" :active.sync="touchOpen">
      <vs-button  class="close"  @click="cancelClose ($event)" >Cancel</vs-button>
  </vs-popup>
  ....
  data () {
      return {
          touchOpen: false
      }
  }
  methods: {
     cancelClose (event) {
         return this.touchOpen = false
     }
  }
```